# Understanding Object Browser in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, delegates

I might be asking very simple question. I am beginner for C#. Can somebody help me how can i use any  ValueChanged delegate in the attached picture. I appreciate your help.

[image: Object Browser image]

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to embed the image. So Stackoverflow has converted that image to link.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom, try this:

```
myAudioSourceTargetCmd.MemberOfTypeValueChanged += MyCallback;

...

void MyCallback()
{
  ...
}
```

Instead of typing code, you can use Visual Studio to help yourself:

Just after typing the += sign, press Tabulation once, watch the tooltip, and press tabulation twice to make the callback code to be generated.

Best coding

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for your response. Let me tell you that Audio_Source_Target_Cmd is a sealed class. Also when i try to instantiate it, it does not let me do it. I tried to get object using Instance property that did not work either. I tried following 'NetworkDB.Audio_Source_Target_Cmd myAudioSourceTragetCmd = new NetworkDB.Audio_Source_Target_Cmd();' and then your suggestion. NetworkDB is just Namespace.

Comment: I can't see the members of Audio_Source_Target_Cmd. May be there is one that might help getting an instance. Or may be the command might be found/instanciated from another object. If you ve got the source code, you can search in source code : Ctrl+maj+F

Comment: These are the memebers of that class Methods
DoInvalidateInstance()

Properties
Instance
RawValue
TypedValue
Value Also i dont see any event defined.